# why error showing: too few arguments to function?

Tags: c++

Even on passing parameters to the function log, error showing too few arguments to function.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int log(int n, int x){
    return (n>1) ? 1 + log(n/x) : 0;
}

int main() {
    int n,x;
    cin>> n>> x;
    cout<< log(n,x);
}
```

I expect the output of log10(1000) to be 3, but few arguments error is shown.

Comment: How many arguments are you passing to the `log` function, in `log(n/x)`? How many, does it expect?

Comment: Your code doesn't contain `log10(1000)`.

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1415873c8c4281b6).  That said, you really sholuld include `<cmath>` if you are using the C++ standard functions.  Also, [get rid of the `using namespace std;`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: @NathanOliver this is a recursion, not a call to a standard function.

Comment: @NathanOliver When trying to reproduce an issue it helps to [use OP's actual code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/08b7389830e2acdb).

Comment: @IgorR. If it is recursion, why aren't they using 2 parameters in the recursive call?

Comment: To avoid confusion, better not giving to your function a name (`log`) widely used in existing library

Comment: @NathanOliver that's exactly what the compiler says :))

Comment: @Yunnosch ok, I've removed it. Just thought it would make the question more clear. (As you can see, people thought he attepted to use `log` from std math lib).

Comment: @Igor I agree that those people obviously needed some help with understanding the question. Still, to me the tag seemed the wrong way. Note however that I did not delete it either. For that it was still too applicable... if you know what I mean. I also feel with those who misunderstood, avoiding that kind of wrong assumptions is very hard....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot the second argument to your log function in the recursive step.

```cpp
return (n>1) ? 1 + log(n/x, x) : 0;
```

---

By the way, you should name your variables something descriptive. For instance instead of using `n` perhaps use `base`.

Comment: In my understanding, the base is `x` here, not `n`

Comment: Welcome to the concept of self-fulfilling prophecy.

Comment: Thanks for the correction and I will do keep the variables descriptive in future.